# Join Fetch: "query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was 

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have the following Model `Activity` with the language-depending property `Title`. The language-dependency is defined with two additional entities `Translation` (Title is of this type, many-to-one) and `TranslationValue` (one-to-many).

If I write the following hql:

```
from Activity act join fetch act.Title join fetch act.Title.TranslationValuesSet
```

This works fine so far. But as soon as I add act into the select-statement, I've got a problem with the join of TranslationValuesSet:

```
select act from Activity act join fetch act.Title join fetch act.Title.TranslationValuesSet
```

`NHibernate.QueryException: Query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=,role=Translation.TranslationValuesSet,tableName=TranslationValue,tableAlias=translatio3_,origin=Translation translatio2_,colums={translatio2_.TranslationId ,className=TranslationValue}}] [select act from Activity act join fetch act.Title join fetch act.Title.TranslationValuesSet`

I can't figure out why Hibernate doesn't like that!?

Thx for any tipps!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

... turns out that I need to define an alias for the first join. This does the trick (notice alias `title`):

```
select act from Activity act join fetch act.Title title join fetch title.TranslationValuesSet
```

Comment: And why is that? It works for me too, after having problems after upgrading Hibernate version. Did they change something? The exact same query was executed properly in JBoss 4.2.2.GA but not in JBoss 6.0.0.Final.

Comment: However, this won't work if you try to select a mix of fields and nested entities :(

Comment: I faced the same issue when upgrading from Hibernate 3.3 to Hibernate 3.6 and no where in the official migration guide(s) have they even mentioned that Query parser behavior might have changed !! Hibernate needs to do a better job with their migration guides !

Comment: You are not supposed to specify an alias for a fetch join, because you're not supposed to use it in the select list.